Invalid payload CryptographicException in 6 .NET Core 8 Apps on a Single Azure Instance without Configured Data Protection
I’m hosting six .NET Core 8 web apps under a single Azure Web App instance. None of the apps explicitly configure the data protection API using services.AddDataProtection(), so they all default to using C:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys for storing data protection keys.
I have identified the active key file in the directory by checking the activationDate and expirationDate elements. Despite this setup, all apps regularly log a System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException to Azure Application Insights approximately every five minutes.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect (Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

I have:

Confirmed all apps access the same key file.
Looked for file access issues or permissions problems.
Checked Azure diagnostics for any related issues without success.

Questions:

How can I further diagnose the cause of this exception based on my current configuration?
Are there recommended changes to the configuration that might resolve these frequent exceptions?


Confirm with program developers that only the apps originating from their own safe system are authorized to be used. Often, there is a clear mandate of either the app's code or its singular existence that tends to restrict its location. However, uncommon or new things also get an equal chance with the existing. This is bad.
To find and fix this:

Check logs: Provide in the appsettings file full path inside the Debug directory so as see log equivalence for the problems.

Update keys: Atcomplete theturn at afrequency of every12 hours daily. If not, call IkeyRingProvider. GetKeRing() to update them.

Guard data: Move them all to one procedure with the same rules in terms of data protection on one data set instead. At times, friends and families are not available for people who may out of their desperation, the service provider is the sole solution and can therefore be relied upon for such a purpose.

Use Azure: In stead of backing up copy of keys, it can be good idea to explore Azure Blob Storage and coding of keys into Azure Key Vault instead. Experts think that these large American tech companies definitely use a poorness of data sharing.


Cloud applications are secure against this approach, which involves also Azure Blob Storage and Azure Key Vault; through this, a clear picture of how to protect your data is obtained.
services.AddDataProtection()
.PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(blobStorage, "keys.xml")
.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(keyVault, clientId, clientSecret);

Data Protection in ASP.NET Core
